# passing object of handlers to v-on and accessing methods

Tags: vue.js

I have a `v-for` loop in which I build up a row of buttons from my data. I also dynamically bind handlers to them and here is the part I am struggling with.

```
<component
  is="button.component"
  v-for="(button, index) in group"
  :key="index"
  v-on="button.handlers"
>
  Text
</component>
```

As you can see, I pass `button.handlers` to the v-on function. My data looks like this:

```
data: {
  group: [
    {
       component: BButton
       value: 'foo',
       handlers: { click: 'update(button.value)' }
    },
    {
       component: CustomFilePickerButton
       value: 'bar',
       handlers: { change: 'uploadFile($event.files)' }
    }
  ]
}
```

Vue complains that the string `'update(value)'` is not a function but I dont know how I can get the equivalent to `v-on:click="update(button.value)"` which would work in the template.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little about the dynamic nature of the handlers? There are many different ways to approach this problem but it's difficult to know which way to take it from the example you've given. It would be useful to know what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @skirtle I updated the question with a more complex example which should show how the dynamic events are meant to be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of `v-on` with object introduces limitations, 'update(button.value)' string cannot be compiled and make use of local `button.value` value because it's defined outside the template.

It would be possible to provide this functionality with custom directive similar to `v-on`.

Otherwise all necessary data needs to be provided to handlers with helper function:

```
<button
  v-for="(button, index) in group"
  :key="index"
  v-on="mapHandlers(button, { value: button.value })"
>

...

methods: {
  mapHandlers(button, data) {
    let remappedHandlers = {};
    for (let eventName in button.handlers) {
      let handler = button.handlers[eventName];
      remappedHandlers[eventName] = e => handler(e, data);
    }
    return remappedHandlers;
  },
  update(e, { value }) { ... }
},
data () {
  return {
    group: [
      {
        value: 'foo',
        handlers: { click: this.update }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Inetersting! Unfortunately I changed the question a but due to a comment. However, this answer seems to be valid anyway!

Comment: I see. Yes, it will work, you can access the entire `e` object in uploadFile or create another wrapper function if uploadFile params are restricted for some reason, `change: ({ files }) => uploadFile(files)`